# Word for someone who is currently in the vicinity, or the grounds of a particular venue

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm sure there must be a word for someone who is currently in the vicinity, or the grounds of a particular venue. For example, I want to say:

> ...while the sounds of the rest of the ______ gang enjoying their dinner spills out of the eating tent...

Something like *occupying*, or *residing*, but not so much that they live there, but rather that they are currently present. Is there a word for that?

Comment: guests, customers, group, party (unless you need to modify gang--then assembled gang, perhaps)

Comment: Why not *visitors* or *guests*?

Comment: Isn't such a word redundant in your sentence? Their happy dinner sounds could only be heard if they were present.

Comment: "Nearby" would seem the natural thing to put there

Comment: @Spagirl I think it's fair to use such a word as it emphasises the closeness of the gang but also makes clear that the narrator is separate from the gang(depending on what word is chosen)